# Unusual adverb position - 'know really' vs. 'really know'

Tags: word-order

> For example, she suggests it is unlikely that the method will be able
> to measure species abundance. But it could monitor bird migrations and
> how they are changing in response to climate change.
>
> “**We don’t know really what you can reliably look at** yet,” she says.
> [Source: Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01850-z)

What is the difference between "we don't really know it" and "we don't know really it"?
The meaning regarding the position of the word "really" is not very clear to me. In the sentence "We don’t know really what you can reliably look at yet" - I think the "really" modifies the verb "know" rather than the clause "what you can reliably look at yet", but I am not absolutely sure. Hence the thread.

Comment: You guys' opinions accepted.  The title and tag of the thread edited.   @Quack E. Duck: Please make your reply an answer, because that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that 'really' modifies the verb 'know,' even though it comes after it. It would be much more usual for this particular adverb to come *before* the verb (as in "we don't really know"), so the usage in your example sentence is **less common**. [This reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position) shows 'really' (which is listed under adverbs of 'degree') coming directly before the verb (they call this "mid position") and says this is its usual place.

[This source](https://englishclub.com/grammar/adverb-position.php) agrees but notes that "There are many exceptions."

And looking at the examples [here](https://espressoenglish.net/position-of-adverbs-in-english-sentences) you'll see there don't really seem to be any examples of the adverb going ***directly after*** the verb. This usage is definitely **not standard**, and I believe is most likely due to the context being reported speech and not writing. The interviewee was probably thinking more about *meaning* than about sentence structure while talking to the reporter, in addition to the fact that we're generally less formal/precise when talking than when writing.

So, I believe the answer to your question is that **this is just a case of nonstandard word order being used due to the speaker composing the sentence 'on the fly,'** and that **there is no difference in meaning compared to the expected phrase "don't really know."**